# Powershell Try Catch and retry?

Tags: loops, powershell, try-catch, finally

I have this script

```
#Change hostname
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.VisualBasic') 
Write-Host "Change hostname " -NoNewLine
$ComputerName = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox('Insert the desired computername:', 'Change hostname') 
Write-Host "- DONE" -ForegroundColor DarkGreen -BackgroundColor green -NoNewline
Write-Host " hostname = $ComputerName "
Rename-Computer -NewName $ComputerName
```

when the computer name gets spaces, it fails cause a hostname cant have spaces.
Can i block the form to have any spaces or does anyone knows how to get back to the inputbox when a error has been created for a re-try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very satisfied with the end result, much thanks

```
#Change hostname
Write-Host "Change hostname " -NoNewLine
do{
    $Failed = $false
    Try{
        $ComputerName = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox('Insert the desired computername:', 'Change hostname') 
        Rename-Computer -NewName $ComputerName -ErrorAction Stop
        Write-Host "- DONE -" -ForegroundColor DarkGreen -BackgroundColor green -NoNewline
        Write-Host "Hostname = $ComputerName" -ForegroundColor DarkGreen -BackgroundColor yellow
    } catch { $Failed = $true }

} while ($Failed)

#Change workgroupname
Write-Host "Change Workgroup " -NoNewLine
do{
    $Failed = $false
    Try{   
        $WorkGroup = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox("Insert the Workgroupname:", 'Change WorkGroupName', 'werkgroep') 
        Add-Computer -WorkGroupName $WorkGroup -ErrorAction Stop
        Write-Host "- DONE -" -ForegroundColor DarkGreen -BackgroundColor green -NoNewline
        Write-Host "Workgroup = $WorkGroup" -ForegroundColor DarkGreen -BackgroundColor yellow
    } catch { $Failed = $true }
} while ($Failed)
```

Answer (score 12):

```
do {
    $ComputerName = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox('Insert the desired computername:','Change hostname')
} while ($ComputerName -match "\s")
```

using a `do{}while()` loop and checking the Input doesn't have any whitespace should resolve your issue, this will re-prompt until a valid hostname is input, if you want to check for any errors at all:

```
do{
    $Failed = $false
    Try{
        $ComputerName = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox('Insert the desired computername:', 'Change hostname') 
        Write-Host "- DONE" -ForegroundColor DarkGreen -BackgroundColor green -NoNewline
        Write-Host " hostname = $ComputerName "
        Rename-Computer -NewName $ComputerName -ErrorAction Stop
    } catch { $Failed = $true }
} while ($Failed)
```

Comment: Tried the first method and that was more then ok.
The second method i cant get the code running as it should could you provide me an example? I like to have the second working cause i have more of this kind of scripts like

Comment: @ThomasvanDalen updated there using your code in the second bit, that should run ok for you.

Comment: TY but it doesnt work, when there is an space a error drops but the inputbox doenst come back to retry

Comment: @ThomasvanDalen one of those weird things in powershell, the error wasn't important enough to trigger Try-Catch, i've updated it there.